# Create mysql function failed in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, function, phpmyadmin

When I try to make this function it always failed.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `f_hadir`(ID INT)
    RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE TMP INT;
        SELECT COUNT(ID_presensi_siswa) into TMP
        FROM presensi_siswa
        WHERE keterangan='Hadir' AND id_siswa=id LIMIT 1;
    RETURN TMP;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

i had similiar code but and it successfully created.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `CategoriesToString`; 
DELIMITER ;; 
CREATE FUNCTION `CategoriesToString`(TID int) RETURNS varchar(500) CHARSET utf8 
BEGIN 
DECLARE result varchar(500); 

SELECT group_concat(Category.Name) INTO result FROM Category 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT CategoryID FROM TopicHasCategory WHERE TopicID = TID) LIMIT 1; 

RETURN result; 
END;; 
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Anyone have idea?

Comment: What 'failed' means? What error you see?

Comment: It turns out to be like first picture. When i click button "go",  nothing happened. The function always not created.